# "Assign to Indexed" C++ Operator Overload Brainteaser

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm writing some funky audio code and trying to use operator overloading to create a very clean and simple API. It's become of a bit of a C++ brainteaser...

What I want would be solved immediately by an "assign to indexed" sort-of-compound operator which I'm pretty sure doesn't exist. Might anyone have any insights on whether the following is possible?

I have 2 object types....

```
Frames frames;  // audio data, contains 1 buffer (float *) for each channel
Sample s;       // a single sample, 1 float for each channel
```

So `Sample` is kind of an orthogonal slice of Frames, ie Frames is NOT an array of `Sample`'s. If you know audio, `Frames` is "non-interleaved", and `Sample` is.

The Holy Grail...

```
s = frames[1];    // statement 1. gets a copy of values in frame 1
frames[1] = s;    // statement 2. replace values in frame 1 with those in Sample s
```

The first one is no problem:

```
// in class Frames...
Sample& operator[](size_t idx) const { 
    Sample s;
    s.left = _leftCh[idx];
    s.right = _rightCh[idx];
    return s;
}
```

But the second assignment is tricky since the above function creates a copy of the data rather than a reference.

I've tried defining Sample with references...

```
class Sample {
public:
    float& L;
    float& R;
    Sample(float& lt, float& rt) : L(lt), R(rt) {};
}
```

But then you can't do something as simple as...

```
Sample s(0.0, 0.0);
s.left = 0.2;
```

Another potential solution would be to have the two statements call two different operator overloads. Then enforce that statement 2 calls this [] overload which returns a new Frames object pointing to the values rather than a `Sample` object:

```
Frames& operator[](size_t idx) {
    // Construct an new Frames object whose which 
    // points to value idx in each channel
    Frames f(_size - idx);
    f._leftCh = &_leftCh[idx];
    f._rightCh = &_rightCh[idx];
    return f;
}
```

And then add an assignment operator to `Frames` which just replaces the first value...

```
Frames& operator=(const Sample& s) {
    _leftCh[0] = s.left;
    _rightCh[0] = s.right;
    return *this;
}
```

The compiler informs me that methods must differ by more than just the return type, but this is resolved by having `const` after the method name for one of the `operator[]` overloads.  Might there be a clue here?  Is there a way to have statement 1 call `Sample& operator[]...` and statment 2 call `Frames& operator[]...`.  Or is there a much better way of accomplishing this??

Thanks for your patience if you've made it this far! Much appreciated...

Comment: The first one **is** a problem, because you're returning a reference to a local variable...

Comment: The first one is wrong: you are returning a reference to a local variable which dies when you exit the operator's scope.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but XCode/LLVM doesn't give me a warning like it does in other cases.  This might be because the reference is immediately copied or possible because I've defined the methods inline.  Seems strange but it works so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
class SampleRef {
  float &left_, &right_;

public:
  SampleRef(float& left, float& right)
    : left_(left), right_(right)
  {}

  operator Sample () {
    return Sample(left_, right_);
  }

  SampleRef& operator= (const Sample &arg) {
    left_ = arg.left;
    right_ = arg.right;
    return *this
  }
};

SampleRef Frames::operator[] (size_t idx) {
  return SampleRef(_leftCh[idx], _rightCh[idx]);
}
```

You can of course also add a `const` overload of `operator[]` which will simply return a `Sample`:

```
Sample Frames::operator[] (size_t idx) const {
  return Sample(_leftCh[idx], _rightCh[idx]);
}
```

Comment: Nice! "Every programming problem can be solved with an additional level of indirection, except too many levels of indirection!".

Comment: I wonder if the semantics of the assignment operator are really what OP intended.

Comment: @juanchopanza I believe so. Quoting the OP's "Holy grail": `frames[1] = s;` "replace values in frame 1 with those in `Sample` `s`".

Comment: Hmmm...that might do it!  Let me give it a quick test.  Slightly annoying to have this intermediate class complicating things for the API end-user but not a big deal if it works. Also would you help me understand how the `const` at the end works?  I thought it just signals the compiler that the method won't alter private vars.  When would `Sample Frames::operator[] const` get called versus `SampleRef& Frames::operator[]`?

Comment: @HariKaramSingh If you have a const object (or a const reference to an object), you can only call `const` member functions on it. Imagine you have code `const Frames frames(generateFrames());` You don't want to be able to do `frames[0] = s;` in such case.

Comment: @HariKaramSingh As to which gets called when: when accessing a non-const object (directly or through a non-const reference), the non-const version gets called. When accessing an object through a const-reference, or accessing a const object, the `const` version gets called.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Just to confirm, with or without the `Sample Frames::operator[] const` method, the call route for `Sample s = frame[i]` would always be `SampleRef Frames::operator[]` followed by `SampleRef operator Sample()` to caste it to Sample?  With the const version of operator[], might it be best to have it throw an exception since it would be an effective no-op? `frames[0]` returns a Sample object on the stack which would be set to `s` and then discarded, right?

Comment: @HariKaramSingh If you don't add the `const` overload, you will not be able to index into a `const Frames` object or through a `const Frames&`. And there's no place for exceptions here - it's perfectly valid to call `Sample s = frame[i];` on both a const and a non-const `frame`.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  Thx @rodrigo for the general principle.  I've solved another problem because of it.  You've both added another dimension to my coding brain :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without overloading just to work out the details? e.g. `sample = frame.getSample(); frame.setSample(sample);` Once the details are worked out to your satisfaction, then you can add the syntactic sugar and overload the `[]` and `=` operators.

It looks like you want to maintain a reference to the original Sample, so that for example:

```
sample.right = oldR;
sample.left = oldL;
f[x] = sample;

sample.right = newR;
sample.left = newL;
newSample = f[x];

assert(sample.right == newSample.right && sample.left == newSample.left);
```

Is this correct? If so, I don't think you can do that, because you "break" up your sample to insert it into the frame, so you lose the original connection.

Comment: Not quite.  I don't want `f[x] = sample` to "link" `sample` to `f[x]`, only assign the values in `sample` to the internal buffer of `f` at frame index `x`. In your example, `newSample.right` should equal `oldR`, `sample` is just a stack var whose values are copied from or assigned into `f[x]`.

Comment: Also, the reason why I didn't go the method-first-then-syntactic-sugar route (though often a good practice) was that I became convinced the operator-based API requirements I was imposing would only allow for a very particular object model which was probably not the one you'd choose from first principles.  It's worth mentioning this whole complication could be avoided probably, if C++ supported properties and accessors.  I'm trying to avoid excess verbosity and parentheses in the final API, e.g. `frames->left()[5]` or `frames->set(sample->left(), index)`